# Research papers on SWE (Sensor Web Enablement) and SOS (Sensor Observation Service) with security

Tags: references, education

I am looking for research papers (conference/journals) on the topic of SWE (Sensor Web Enablement) and SOS (Sensor Observation Service) also dealing/including security aspects.

I have already found some sources (after cleaning up, will post them here too) but you could post any expert material or websources where to search.

Answer (score 1):

- [Workshop on Sensor Web Enablement 2011](http://sensorweb.geomatics.ucalgary.ca/gsw/swe2011)

You can also find some papers from the previous SWE workshops in IEEEXplore.

Answer (score 1):

If by "security aspects", you mean SWE/SOS as used in security systems, you might try googling "alternatives to incarceration gps".

Some might consider this a form of [geoslavery](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/is-geoslavery-complicity-a-violation-of-gisp-code-of-ethics). Coincidentally, a disproportionate number of the companies in this market, like [GpsAim](http://www.gpsaim.net/english/), seem to be based south of the [Mason-Dixon line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Dixon_Line).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the publications related to "Geoshield":
https://sites.google.com/site/geoshieldproject/home

Some related conf slides: http://www.slideshare.net/mantonovic/supsi-geo-shieldsgm2011